# how to crop a part of an image in c# and leave the white part, where it has been cut?

Tags: c#, image, crop, shapes

I have a problem. I want to cut a part of an image, but not to save the part that was cut. I want to have the image I had before with white shape, where the part which I cut was before.
Can you help?

Comment: I'm green at coding. I just tried to crop image using rectangle, and it is working, but I get the part I cropped. Not empty part of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to cut a part of an image, but not to save the part that was cut.

Surely you just want to draw on the image then?

If that's the case use the `Graphics` class and draw a filled in `Rectangle` on top of it.

```
public void RemoveSectionFromImage(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle section, Color color)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, section);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have to change pixels of the chosen part for white color.

Comment: @Mrówka `FillRectangle` draws a filled in rectangle onto the image of the specified colour, location and size.